# Google Cloud Health Check floods my VM?

Tags: cloud, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

I am quite new to the Google Cloud Platform, but I have setup a Compute Engine with a LAMP server, in addition, I have setup a Google Cloud SQL, which I connect to.

The last two days, the connection attempts / questions to be database has gone haywire. When I delete associated files that connect to the DB from the Compute Engine, all connections stop (obviously). This tells me, that some files might be accessed a lot on my compute engine?

Either way, my access.log has several sequences that looks like below. Is this my server getting "spammed" by Google Health Checks - or should I look out for any other signs of being spammed by bots?

Thans in advance!

```
130.211.1.220 - - [25/Oct/2016:05:55:19 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 16692 "-" "GoogleHC/1.0"
130.211.1.197 - - [25/Oct/2016:05:55:20 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 16410 "-" "GoogleHC/1.0"
130.211.1.219 - - [25/Oct/2016:05:55:22 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 16410 "-" "GoogleHC/1.0"
130.211.3.230 - - [25/Oct/2016:05:55:23 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 16692 "-" "GoogleHC/1.0"
130.211.1.213 - - [25/Oct/2016:05:55:23 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 16692 "-" "GoogleHC/1.0"
130.211.1.150 - - [25/Oct/2016:05:55:23 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 16410 "-" "GoogleHC/1.0"
130.211.1.220 - - [25/Oct/2016:05:55:24 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 16692 "-" "GoogleHC/1.0"
130.211.1.197 - - [25/Oct/2016:05:55:25 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 16410 "-" "GoogleHC/1.0"
130.211.1.219 - - [25/Oct/2016:05:55:27 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 16410 "-" "GoogleHC/1.0"
130.211.3.230 - - [25/Oct/2016:05:55:28 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 16692 "-" "GoogleHC/1.0"
130.211.1.213 - - [25/Oct/2016:05:55:28 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 16692 "-" "GoogleHC/1.0"
130.211.1.150 - - [25/Oct/2016:05:55:28 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 16410 "-" "GoogleHC/1.0"
130.211.1.220 - - [25/Oct/2016:05:55:29 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 16692 "-" "GoogleHC/1.0"
130.211.1.197 - - [25/Oct/2016:05:55:30 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 16410 "-" "GoogleHC/1.0"
130.211.1.219 - - [25/Oct/2016:05:55:32 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 16410 "-" "GoogleHC/1.0"
130.211.3.230 - - [25/Oct/2016:05:55:33 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 16692 "-" "GoogleHC/1.0"
130.211.1.213 - - [25/Oct/2016:05:55:33 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 16692 "-" "GoogleHC/1.0"
130.211.1.150 - - [25/Oct/2016:05:55:33 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 16410 "-" "GoogleHC/1.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have opened up a ticket with google about this as this is happening to the two app engine instances I have. They have cost me around $200 in almost three months - I have not been using them and they are not being spammed or hit by other bots. The only traffic I see are these constant health checks. Below is the response from Google. (I have a video of tail -f of the access logs - it shows several pings every second. https://vimeo.com/214891548
I wrote them back saying their explanation was not acceptable.)

Response:
Greetings!

Thank you for contacting Google Cloud Platform Support.
My name is [] and I will be assisting you with your support case.

I understand that you are experiencing instance health checks in almost every second. Actually, you are not being billed for the health checks that are appearing. Also by default, the health check interval is every 5 sec, assuming that you didn't update your health check setting in your app.yaml.

If by any chance, you need to know more about how Health Checks work, you may visit this link [1]. And for the default configuration of Health Check, you may refer to this link [2].

I truly hope this information was helpful. Feel free to let us know if you require further assistance or have further questions in this regard.

Have a nice day!

Warm Regards,
Mike
Google Cloud Platform Support

[1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/how-instances-are-managed
[2] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#health_checks

Comment: I'm getting the same thing, and that indeed is an unacceptable answer. I'll follow up if I hear anything different.

Comment: My health checker just calmed down after I changed the check interval from 60 to 300.